# How to stop an OSGI Application from command line

Tags: java, bash, osgi, shutdown

I do have a running osgi (equinox container) application. It will been started via a bash script. [See felix gogo shell](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-remote-shell.html)

```
java -jar ... _osgi.jar -console 1234 &
```

This all works pretty well and I also can stop it via

```
telnet localhost 1234
<osgi>stop 0
```

But what I am looking for is how can I embed this into a bash script to stop the osgi application.

I already tried this

```
echo stop 0 | telnet localhost 1234
```

but this doesn't work. So if someone has idea how to put this in a bash script, please let me know.

Comment: have not you forgot echo from your command? echo stop 0 | telnet localhost 1234

Comment: I edited the answer, but this is not the reason why it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Telneting into the Gogo shell seems like an awfully fragile solution. Why not write your application to support standard POSIX signal handling? Then you could simply kill it with `kill -s TERM <pid>`.

For example the following bundle activator installs a shutdown hook that cleanly shuts down the framework, equivalently to `stop 0`:

```java
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.Framework;

public class ShutdownHookActivator implements BundleActivator {

    @Override
    public void start(final BundleContext context) {
        Thread hook = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Shutdown hook invoked, stopping OSGi Framework.");
                try {
                    Framework systemBundle = context.getBundle(0).adapt(Framework.class);
                    systemBundle.stop();
                    System.out.println("Waiting up to 2s for OSGi shutdown to complete...");
                    systemBundle.waitForStop(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Failed to cleanly shutdown OSGi Framework: " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        System.out.println("Installing shutdown hook.");
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(hook);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

NB: if you are in control of the launcher code that starts the OSGi Framework, you should probably install the shutdown hook there rather from a separate bundle.

### Update

In bash, the `$!` variable evaluates to the PID of the last executed background command. You can save this into your own variable for later reference, e.g.:

```
# Launch app:
java -jar ... &
MY_PID=$!

# Later when you want to stop your app:
kill $MY_PID
```

Comment: ok, thats a nice solution. But one question, how do I get the <pid> to add this to a bash script. Yes maybe this is another question.

Comment: @Christian In bash, the variable `$!` evaluates to the PID of the last executed background command. Save this into your own variable immediately after launching `java -jar ... &`.

Comment: The cast of context.getBundle(0) to Framework is not guaranteed to work. The spec does not require that the system bundle's Bundle object is an instanceof Framework. See 4.2.1 in the spec: "The framework object can be seen as the system bundle, though the framework object and the system bundle do not have to be identical, implementations are allowed to implement them in different objects." So your example should avoid the cast to Framework.

Comment: I updated the example code to adapt the system bundle to Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can for instance use expect, if there is no other way than telnet to close the application.

http://www.tamas.io/automatic-scp-using-expect-and-bash/

Comment: I agree with Neil, this is a fragile and complex solution for a simple problem. Each operating system has ways to tell processes to quit and by implementing a shutdown hook your Java/OSGi program can respond to that and cleanly shutdown.