# OSGi @Activate breaks when method has parameters. Error: activate method not found; Component will fail

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to implement a graceful shutdown hook to my OSGi based app. I'm implementing it in a bundle as I don't have direct access to the launcher source.

Here is the class:

```
/**
 * Shutdown Hook for OSGi
 * Based On: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32216407/5284104
 */
@Component()
public class ShutdownHookActivator{

    @Activate
    public void start(ComponentContext cc, BundleContext bc, Map<String,Object> config) {
        Thread hook = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Stopping OSGi Framework.");
            try {
                Framework systemBundle = bc.getBundle(0).adapt(Framework.class);
                systemBundle.stop();
                System.out.println("Waiting up to 2s for OSGi shutdown to complete...");
                systemBundle.waitForStop(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Failed to cleanly shutdown OSGi Framework: " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        System.out.println("Installing shutdown hook.");
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(hook);
    }
}
```

But whenever I launch it it returns an error:

> ERROR: [ShutdownHookActivator(8)] activate method [start] not found;
>   Component will fail

But when I remove the parameters from the **start** method then everything works. So now I'm confused, I've seen examples where the @Activate method had parameters that are auto-injected by the OSGi framework (http://enroute.osgi.org/services/org.osgi.service.component.html), and others that are just empty, so from what I understand this should work. (Feels like in OSGi it's all about luck)

What is the proper way to implement this by using DS Annotations and getting the Framework BundleContext? Is it even possible?

EDIT:
OSGi Environment:
BndTools (aQute Launcher?)
Apache Felix SCR 2.0.12 (OSGi DS Annotations - 6.0.1)
Source can be seen here: https://github.com/Jafre13/ISS-Product

EDIT 2:
The auto-generated ShutdownHookActivator.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.3.0" name="dk.sdu.sso.sred.utils.ShutdownHookActivator" activate="start">
  <implementation class="dk.sdu.sso.sred.utils.ShutdownHookActivator"/>
</scr:component>
```

Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1512410080758
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: dk.sdu.sso.sred
Bundle-SymbolicName: dk.sdu.sso.sred
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0.201712041754
Created-By: 1.8.0_151 (Oracle Corporation)
Import-Package: javax.security.auth.x500,junit.framework,org.junit,org
 .xml.sax,org.xml.sax.ext,org.xml.sax.helpers
Private-Package: dk.sdu.sso.sred.cmd,dk.sdu.sso.sred.lingpipe,dk.sdu.s
 so.sred.api;version="1.0.0",dk.sdu.sso.sred,com.aliasi.test.unit.xml,
 com.aliasi.test.unit.io,com.aliasi.suffixarray,com.aliasi.test.unit.u
 til,com.aliasi.test.unit.crf,com.aliasi.matrix,com.aliasi.test.unit.s
 entences,com.aliasi.test.unit,com.aliasi.tag,com.aliasi.test.unit.hmm
 ,com.aliasi.chunk,com.aliasi.coref,com.aliasi.spell,com.aliasi.test.u
 nit.chunk,com.aliasi.test.unit.features,com.aliasi.coref.matchers,com
 .aliasi.lm,com.aliasi.test.unit.coref,com.aliasi.cluster,com.aliasi.f
 eatures,com.aliasi.test.unit.symbol,com.aliasi.io,com.aliasi.test.uni
 t.tokenizer,com.aliasi.sentences,com.aliasi.test.unit.coref.matchers,
 com.aliasi.test.unit.spell,com.aliasi.test.unit.corpus,com.aliasi.uti
 l,com.aliasi.dca,com.aliasi.symbol,com.aliasi.test.unit.lm,com.aliasi
 .dict,com.aliasi.test.unit.tag,com.aliasi.corpus,com.aliasi.classify,
 com.aliasi.test.unit.dca,com.aliasi.tokenizer,com.aliasi.test.unit.cl
 assify,com.aliasi.crf,com.aliasi.test.unit.cluster,com.aliasi.stats,c
 om.aliasi.test.unit.stats,com.aliasi.test.unit.dict,com.aliasi.test.u
 nit.matrix,com.aliasi.test.unit.suffixarray,com.aliasi.xml,com.aliasi
 .hmm,dk.sdu.sso.sred.utils,org.apache.felix.service.command,org.osgi.
 framework;version="1.8",org.osgi.service.component;version="1.3"
Provide-Capability: osgi.service;objectClass:List<String>="dk.sdu.sso.
 sred.api.SRedAPI",osgi.service;objectClass:List<String>="dk.sdu.sso.s
 red.cmd.ModelCommands",osgi.service;objectClass:List<String>="dk.sdu.
 sso.sred.cmd.SRedCommands"
Require-Capability: osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=osgi.compo
 nent)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))",osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.e
 e=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/dk.sdu.sso.sred.SRed.xml,OSGI-INF/dk.sdu.s
 so.sred.cmd.ModelCommands.xml,OSGI-INF/dk.sdu.sso.sred.cmd.SRedComman
 ds.xml,OSGI-INF/dk.sdu.sso.sred.utils.ShutdownHookActivator.xml
Tool: Bnd-3.5.0.201709291849
```

Comment: What version of the DS spec do you use at build time? What version of scr do you use at runtime?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider The DS spec is 6.0.1. The SCR runtime is 2.0.12.

Comment: That is pretty current so I do not expect any issues resulting from an older version. Maybe not all your parameters are support at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Manifest it is obvious why your problem happens. You have the OSGi APIs as private package. This means that the classes are embedded into your jar and so they will be incompatible to the spec classes used by the framework and DS.

So the solution is to make sure you only use private package for stuff you really need to embed. Never use it for OSGi api packages. You need to have an import for them to work.

Comment: It yields the same result. It still says "ERROR: [ShutdownHookActivator(20)] activate method [start] not found; Component will fail". It always fails until I remove all parameters, then it does works, but then I cannot access the Frameworks BundleContext.

Comment: Can you post the Manifest (especially the imports) and the xml that is generated for your component(You find it in the jar)?

Comment: Updated the main post. I was using start(BundleContext bc) while generating the JAR file.

Comment: Christian is right. You are not importing the OSGi packages: org.osgi.service.component and org.osgi.framework. So SCR cannot use your activate method since it does not have a ComponentContext and BundleContext which are the same types as your private types in your bundle.